# How to add reaction to an embed message JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to send and embed message when I do the command ~verify and then it sends an embed message and I cant find how to add to there a reaction.

I did already the embed message and sent it but can add the reaction

```
import Main.Bot;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.MessageBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.awt.*;

public class Verify extends ListenerAdapter {



    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e){
        if(e.getAuthor().isBot()) return;

        if(e.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(Bot.prefix+"verify")){
            EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();
            embedBuilder.setColor(Color.red);
            embedBuilder.setTitle("Verify yourself!");
            embedBuilder.addField("How?","Press the ✔ reaction to verify",false);
            embedBuilder.setFooter("Created by SlayZBro#3501",e.getGuild().getIconUrl());

            e.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            e.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).queue();
            embedBuilder.clear();


        }
    }


}
```

I need to add the reaction to the embed message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the sent message in the callback for `queue()` and add reactions there:

```java
channel.sendMessage(embed).queue(message -> message.addReaction(reaction).queue());
```

To add multiple questions you can use a multiline lambda:

```java
channel.sendMessage(embed).queue(message -> {
  message.addReaction(reaction1).queue();
  message.addReaction(reaction2).queue();
  message.addReaction(reaction3).queue();
});
```

Also there is no reason to clear the `EmbedBuilder` because it won't be used again in your code. Builders are usually not resources that need to be closed/cleared unless you use them again and don't want the previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

I understood how to do it. Just need to add this line

```
 e.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).complete().addReaction("✔").queue();
```

Comment: Its better to use queue(...) and do it in the callback.