# Adding emoji reaction by unicode not working

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Currently, I am making a music discord bot and I want it to display the list of songs it is currently playing.

The user should be able to interact with the list by moving to each page with a left arrow and right arrow emoji.

The problem is that, when I try to react to the message via a unicode, it does not seems to work as follows:

```
message.addReaction("U+2B05").queue();
message.addReaction("U+2B07").queue();
```

it throws an error saying that the Emoji is not found during runtime, even though that is the respective unicode for the emoji I wanted to sent.
I have tried to use `2B05` or `Left Arrow` in the string and it does not work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encountered the same issue before, though one of the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761174/how-to-add-reaction-to-an-embed-message-jda) question helped me.
Specifically, one of the answer was:

> I understood how to do it. Just need to add this line
>   `e.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).complete().addReaction("✔").queue();`

Apparently adding the emoji directly into the string works.

Do this instead:

```
message.addReaction("➡").queue();
message.addReaction("⬅").queue();
```

Comment: As of version 4+ you can use the other notation with `U+` too.