# How to add multiple reactions to embed message with JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to make a bot respond to a command with an embed message that has multiple reactions under it.
I have got it working to the point that it adds 1 reaction but I need to add different reactions as well, like this: (http://prntscr.com/qd8da4) There are a lot of tutorials online that add 1 reaction, but none that add multiple.

I am using the latest version of the Discord JDA.

The code I currently have is:

```java
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(DiscordBot.prefix + "info")) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel(); // Channel the command was sent in.

        EmbedBuilder info = new EmbedBuilder();
        info.setTitle("Server Info");
        info.setDescription("Info About the bot.");
        info.addField("Creator", "Name", false);
        info.setColor(0xf45642);
        info.setTimestamp(Instant.now());
        channel.sendMessage(info.build()).queue(message -> message.addReaction("✔️").queue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add reaction to an embed message JDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761174/how-to-add-reaction-to-an-embed-message-jda)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem myself as there wasn't really a native way to do what I want which was to have certain bot actions when a reaction was clicked.

I ended up creating a couple helper classes that allow the program to have callbacks when reactions are clicked:

The following is the reaction which will listen for reactions to be clicked:

```
public class ReactionListener<T> {

  private final Map<String, Consumer<Message>> reactions;
  private final long userId;
  private volatile T data;
  private Long expiresIn, lastAction;
  private boolean active;

  public ReactionListener(long userId, T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.userId = userId;
    reactions = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    active = true;
    lastAction = System.currentTimeMillis();
    expiresIn = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
  }

  public void disable() {
    this.active = false;
  }

  /**
   * The time after which this listener expires which is now + specified time
   * Defaults to now+5min
   *
   * @param timeUnit time units
   * @param time     amount of time units
   */
  public void setExpiresIn(TimeUnit timeUnit, long time) {
    expiresIn = timeUnit.toMillis(time);
  }

  /**
   * Check if this listener has specified emote
   *
   * @param emote the emote to check for
   * @return does this listener do anything with this emote?
   */
  public boolean hasReaction(String emote) {
    return reactions.containsKey(emote);
  }

  /**
   * React to the reaction :')
   *
   * @param emote   the emote used
   * @param message the message bound to the reaction
   */
  public void react(String emote, Message message) {
    if (hasReaction(emote)) reactions.get(emote).accept(message);
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  /**
   * Register a consumer for a specified emote
   * Multiple emote's will result in overriding the old one
   *
   * @param emote    the emote to respond to
   * @param consumer the behaviour when emote is used
   */
  public void registerReaction(String emote, Consumer<Message> consumer) {
    reactions.put(emote, consumer);
  }

  /**
   * @return list of all emotes used in this reaction listener
   */
  public Set<String> getEmotes() {
    return reactions.keySet();
  }

  /**
   * updates the timestamp when the reaction was last accessed
   */
  public void updateLastAction() {
    lastAction = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  /**
   * When does this reaction listener expire?
   *
   * @return timestamp in millis
   */
  public Long getExpiresInTimestamp() {
    return lastAction + expiresIn;
  }

  public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }
}
```

Next we want to handle the reactions as they are clicked. This method requires the current logged in userId to make sure only that users actions will be recorded and no one elses. It can be modified to be global if others can react too.:

```
public class ReactionHandler {

  private final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ReactionListener<?>>> reactions;

  private ReactionHandler() {
    reactions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  }

  public synchronized void addReactionListener(long guildId, Message message, ReactionListener<?> handler) {
    addReactionListener(guildId, message, handler, true);
  }

  public synchronized void addReactionListener(long guildId, Message message, ReactionListener<?> handler, boolean queue) {
    if (handler == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (message.getChannelType().equals(ChannelType.TEXT)) {
      if (!PermissionUtil.checkPermission(message.getTextChannel(), message.getGuild().getSelfMember(), Permission.MESSAGE_ADD_REACTION)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    if (!reactions.containsKey(guildId)) {
      reactions.put(guildId, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }
    if (!reactions.get(guildId).containsKey(message.getIdLong())) {
      for (String emote : handler.getEmotes()) {
        RestAction<Void> action = message.addReaction(emote);
        if (queue) action.queue(); else action.complete();
      }
    }
    reactions.get(guildId).put(message.getIdLong(), handler);
  }

  public synchronized void removeReactionListener(long guildId, long messageId) {
    if (!reactions.containsKey(guildId)) return;
    reactions.get(guildId).remove(messageId);
  }

  /**
   * Handles the reaction
   *
   * @param channel   TextChannel of the message
   * @param messageId id of the message
   * @param userId    id of the user reacting
   * @param reaction  the reaction
   */
  public void handle(TextChannel channel, long messageId, long userId, MessageReaction reaction) {
    ReactionListener<?> listener = reactions.get(channel.getGuild().getIdLong()).get(messageId);
    if (!listener.isActive() || listener.getExpiresInTimestamp() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
      reactions.get(channel.getGuild().getIdLong()).remove(messageId);
    } else if ((listener.hasReaction(reaction.getReactionEmote().getName())) && listener.getUserId() == userId) {
      reactions.get(channel.getGuild().getIdLong()).get(messageId).updateLastAction();
      Message message = channel.retrieveMessageById(messageId).complete();
      listener.react(reaction.getReactionEmote().getName(), message);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Do we have an event for a message?
   *
   * @param guildId   discord guild-id of the message
   * @param messageId id of the message
   * @return do we have an handler?
   */
  public boolean canHandle(long guildId, long messageId) {
    return reactions.containsKey(guildId) && reactions.get(guildId).containsKey(messageId);
  }

  public synchronized void removeGuild(long guildId) {
    reactions.remove(guildId);
  }

  /**
   * Delete expired handlers
   */
  public synchronized void cleanCache() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ReactionListener<?>>>> iterator = reactions.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Map.Entry<Long, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ReactionListener<?>>> mapEntry = iterator.next();
      mapEntry.getValue().values().removeIf(listener -> !listener.isActive() || listener.getExpiresInTimestamp() < now);
      if (mapEntry.getValue().values().isEmpty()) {
        reactions.remove(mapEntry.getKey());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then with both of these libraries in hand we can implement them in our messages as such.

```
channel.sendMessage(info.build()).queue((msg) -> {

  ReactionListener<String> handler = new ReactionListener<>(userId, msg.getId());
  handler.setExpiresIn(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 1);
  handler.registerReaction("✔️", (ret) -> foo());
  handler.registerReaction("X",  (ret) -> bar());

  reactionHandler.addReactionListener(guild.getIdLong(), msg, handler);
});
```